# killall <processname> throughout the system

Tags: process, kill

I'm opening two terminal windows.

**Terminal 1**
- I run process1

**Terminal 2**
- I run process2

I then terminate both process using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in each window.

I type `killall -9 process1` in Terminal 2 , and there's no feedback.

I realise later that in Terminal 1, process1 is not really killed.

How do I kill process1 in Terminal 1 from Terminal 2 console?

Comment: `kill -9` will always kill a process. How are you determining that "process1 is not really killed"? Note that you might need to press Enter in Terminal 1 for the shell to report that the process was indeed killed.

Comment: Ctrl-Z does not _terminate_ processes. They are _stopped_ and can be _continued._

Comment: Hi @GregHewgill it turned out that that was indeed the case. everytime I typed ps, only would it report that the process was killed. My issue with "the process not killed" turned out to be an error caused by something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
process="$1"
null=/dev/null

if pkill -9 "$process" &> $null ; then

    if pgrep "$process" &> $null ; then
        echo "$process is still running"
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "$process killed successfully"
    exit 0
fi

echo "Process $process not found"
exit 1
```

---

To use: `./script.sh process1`

To see the output of `pkill` and `pgrep` remove the respective `&> $null`